# flag provided but not defined: -ethstats

Tags: rinkeby

I am trying to work with rinkeby testnet and I downloaded rinkeby.json genesis file and successfully created genesis block now i am trying to run this command to sync all blocks but I am facing this error. Help!

geth --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --cache=512 --ethstats='yournode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io' --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303

Comment: This command works for me. What version of Geth are you running?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me too. As you mentioned my geth version was not upto date so had issue. Thank you.